# Function to open all Org files in a folder recursively

Tags: org-mode, find-file

I am looking for a way to open all Org (or Fountain) files in a folder using one function.

Essentially, I am seeking to open all available files of a certain type (`.org` or `.fountain`) within a folder tree.

Comment: Welcome.  Could you please ellaborate.  Do want to open all files individually or just get a directory listing?

Comment: I should have been a bit more descriptive :) I am seeking to open all available files within a folder tree. The answer by Harald is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Very good.  You should accept his answer, and add the extra explanation of your problem to the body of your question.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, I am still learning how to use StackExchange properly.

Comment: No problem.  We are here to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution for org files. I wouldn't recognise a Fountain file if I saw one, so you'd have to provide that one yourself. The second argument to `directory-files-recursively` is a regular expression.

```
(defun open-org-files-recursively (dirname)
  "Search DIRNAME recursively for org files, and open them all."
  (interactive "D")
  (mapc #'find-file (directory-files-recursively dirname "\\.org$" nil)))
```

**Edit:** The last argument to `directory-files-recursively` should be `nil`, in order to exclude directories whose name ends with `.org`.

Comment: Great. This function motivates me to learn some elisp.

By the way, fountain files are .fountain, and they are a major mode to write theatre or screen scripts.

Comment: @PeterPrevos if you are going to attack elisp, I recommend taking the time to wade through the elisp tutorial, with the elisp manual as a supplement, rather than focusing on the elisp manual directly.